# Doubt in understanding GANs

Tags: machine-learning, gan

I was going through original GAN paper: Goodfellow, Ian, et al. "Generative adversarial nets." Advances in neural information processing systems. 2014. Link: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf

For proving optimal D, eq 2, they have rewritten the objective function in equation 3. It is:
[image: Equation 3 image]

So, essentially they have changed $p(z)$ to $p(x)$ and $g(z)$ to $x$.
My question is how can this be done?

p.s: Is this the correct place to ask such question? Is there a dedicated place where I can ask questions related to specific sub topics of ML? I also asked at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639114/doubt-in-understanding-gans

Comment: check out the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). they're changing the measure

Comment: There is an encompassing parenthesis missing in (3).

Comment: Ok i have had this problem before.Actually,it can be proved with the Radon therom in Measure theory.

Comment: is Equation 3 the final developed objective function of traditional GAN? what is the name of this loss function, and is it used anywhere else in machine learning?