# What is the objective function of GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, reinforcement-learning, gan

Generative adversarial networks (GAN) solve some unique objective function or loss not used by other learning models, it has a name. There are already several variants of GAN  so I'm getting conflicting information about what the traditional objective function is. could anyone spell out the formula with some commentary on

- the usual optimization algorithm used, and other considerations, used to solve the objective function
- variants to the original objective that attempt to overcome issues with traditional GAN such as mode collapse

even the original paper and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404506/understanding-the-gan-loss-function-from-the-original-paper) discussion are stuck on expected values, so I'm interested in the final developed form of GAN.

Comment: I guess that you could remove expected values from the formulas. If you remove the expected value you would get the loss function computed on a single data point.

Comment: you mean like the formula here, where they still are confused with variables used? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462176/doubt-in-understanding-gans

Comment: I meant if the problem is the expected value, you can look at those formulas in the link as if there weren't expected values. For example, you could say that a neural network for classification optimizes: $\min{ \int_x H(p_x,q_x) } = \min{ -\int_x \sum_i p_x(i) \log{q_x(i)} }. Where $H(p_x,q_x)$ is the categorical cross entropy.

Comment: what i linked *does* have GAN's formula without expectations. but it doesn't necessarily provide more clarity telling from the comments there

Comment: @Simone here is a related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486880/is-the-gan-min-max-loss-function-a-convex-optimization-problem