# Is the GAN min-max loss function a convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, loss-functions, gan, convex

The GAN loss function is binary cross entropy consisting of a discriminator function $D(x)$ and generator function $G(z)$.

$$
\min_{G} \max_{D} V(D,G)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}}[\log D(x)] + \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_{z}(z)}[\log(1-D(G(z)))]
$$

is it solved with linear programming? dynamic programming? or convex optimization, and if so quadratic programming? how can you tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loss function depends on the generator output $G(z)$ and discriminators outputs $D(x)$ and $D(G(z))$. Both generator and discriminator are usually neural networks parametrized by some parameter vectors $\theta_{G}$ and $\theta_{D}$. Therefore, the GAN loss function is optimized with respect to $\theta_{G}$ and $\theta_{D}$. Such loss function is not convex, and is usually solved by gradient methods (SGD, Adam etc.).
According to this GAN tutorial https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00160.pdf (section 3.2.2 on page 22), the optimization problem would be convex, if we would solve the problem directly in the functional spaces of D and G instead of the parameter spaces of $\theta_{G}$ and $\theta_{D}$.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of GAN optimization with game theory perspective

> Since these two networks shoot information at each other, it could be
> portrayed as a game where one guesses if the input is real or not.
>
> The GAN framework is a non-convex, two-player, non-cooperative game
> with continuous, high-dimensional parameters, in which each player
> wants to minimize its cost function. The optimum of this process takes
> the name of Nash Equilibrium - where each player will not perform any
> better by changing a strategy, given the fact that the other player
> doesn't change their strategy.
>
> However, GANs are typically trained using gradient-descent techniques
> that are designed to find the low value of a cost function and not
> find the Nash Equilibrium of a game.

[Source](https://www.stackabuse.com/introduction-to-gans-with-python-and-tensorflow/)